# Gdrive API error 403 for transferring ownership "Rate limit exceeded. User message: "Sorry, you have exceeded your sharing quota."

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

There is no documentation on any sharing quota. My limited understanding based on some searches is that it's in place to prevent some kind of spamming.

Google will not let a user transfer ownership of a file outside of the domain in which it is already owned, so I'm obviously not spamming people in my own private Gsuite domain.

Is there a way to lift this restriction? Is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 2):

As stated by this documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_rate_limit_exceeded):

> A `sharingRateLimitExceeded` error occurs when the user has reached a sharing limit. This error is often linked with an email limit.

In order to fix the error, you can try the following:

> - Do not send emails when sharing lot of files.
> - If one user is making a lot of requests on behalf of many users of a G Suite domain, consider a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) with authority delegation to impersonate the owner of each document to share (setting the [quotaUser parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/query-parameters)).

Moreover, you can check the status of your quota for the `Drive API` by accessing the Google Cloud Project for it and checking the **Quotas** section:

[image: GCP Quotas Drive API]

#### Reference

- [Google Drive API Resolve Errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors);
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account);
- [Viewing your Quota](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#viewing_your_quota)

Comment: Super helpful thank you, this fixed my issue. Using a service account with domain-wide delegation was the key. However the sharing quota or email quota info is still nowhere to be found. Moot at this point though since it's working. Thank you.